# jmeter how to apply 1 second delay for every user for file upload

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a scenario, where I need to check how much time it will take for a file upload. So the scenario goes like this :

```
User Signs in -> User selects the file to upload -> user check if file is uploaded.
```

We need to check this for 10 users. As of now we have given 10 login credentials with a ramp up of 1 user per second. So we are setting up concurrency before user clicking upload button.

But I need each user to click upload button after every 1 second. So 1st user clicks at 1st second 2nd user at 2nd second. Like that 10th user will click at 10th second.

Is this achievable ? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want your **Upload** requests to be executed at rate `1 request per 1 second` the easiest option is adding a [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) as a child of this "Upload" request and setting its rate to `1 RPS`

[image: JMeter Throughput Shaping Timer]

This Timer will "tell" JMeter to pause the threads in order to reach 1 request per second throughput and given Timer's [scope](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) is limited to the "Upload" request sampler - only this one will be paused.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Throughput Shaping Timer Demo]

More information: [Using JMeter’s Throughput Shaping Timer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin)